# how to match string exclude substring use re2

Tags: re2

use re2 https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax

```
abc_abc_code
abc_titer_code
abc_google_twitter_code
abc_twitter_twitter_code
abc_google_google_google_google_code

abc_abc_app_code
abc_titer_app_code
abc_google_twitter_app_code
abc_twitter_twitter_app_code
abc_google_google_google_google_app_code
```

`abc_[a-zA-Z0-9_:]_app_code` This can match last 5 string.

How to only match top 5 string?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The difference between to top 5 strings and the bottom 5 is that the top ones end with `_code` and the bottom ones end with `_app_code`, everything else, in this case, remain the same.

To match all the top 5 strings then you might want to use a [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
^abc_[a-zA-Z_]+(?<!_app)_code$
```

- `^abc_` to indicate the string starting
- `_code$` to indicate the string ending
- `(?<!_app)` tell the engine to not match if `_code` is preceded by `_app`
- `[a-zA-Z_]+` to indicate everything in this range that lies between

You can experiment with this regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/6C1GAa/1)

Comment: Maybe my question is not being well described. I want to only match the top 5 exclude the bottom 5.

Comment: Edited answer, should match only top 5 now @leavest

Comment: Negative lookbehind is not supported by re2.

Answer (score 0):

A re2-compatible solution:

```
^abc_(?:[a-zA-Z_:]{0,3}|[a-zA-Z_:]*(?:[a-zA-Z:][a-zA-Z_:]{3}|[a-zA-Z_:][b-zA-Z_:][a-zA-Z_:]{2}|[a-zA-Z_:]{2}[a-oq-zA-Z_:][a-zA-Z_:]|[a-zA-Z_:]{3}[a-oq-zA-Z_:]))_code$
```

It's not pretty, but I can't think of anything better with lookaround assertions missing from re2 (apart from not using re2 to solve this).

Here's a Go Playground link with a test: https://go.dev/play/p/rnXKLMIJyPk